# I cannot boot into my Linux distro

Tags: 18.04, fsck, parted

I adopted a Dell XPS 13, updated the Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, and gave it the MacBuntu environment for my girlfriend to use. Everything worked great! Then I got it in my head to run Steam, mainly to play Civilization 6. Experiments creating a swap file to manage resources however seemed to backfire.  Following [It's Foss](https://itsfoss.com/create-swap-file-linux/). Working the command line I `swapoff -a` to turned off the active file, and fallocate a new one with the name swapfile, 2G.   Either at this point or when I progressed to mkswap I got a warning that I was 'eliminating' the old swap file. Behind the Terminal I saw my Activity Bar and Chrome disappear. Closing the terminal I couldn't open it again. No programs were available, and the computer did not shut down normally. I had to hold down the power button to turn off the computer.

A previous question addressed that particular issue, though without a clear answer ("Challenges to Creating and using swap files in Ubuntu 18.04"). This Bash history shows my activity up to that point I think.

[image]

I enter recovery mode, try `fsck`, and it gives me a clean bill of health. When I resume normal boot however, nothing. Just a cursor. When I attempt to boot past it I hang on the Ubuntu splash screen. I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and get a long list of Failures, a few OKs, and one or two dependencies. Here's a partial list I retyped myself.

```
Failed to start network name resolution, see systemct1 status systemd-resolved.service
Failed to start network time synchronisation see systemd-timesyncd.service for details
Failed to start Bluetooth service: systemct1 status bluetooth.service for details
Failed to start Modem Manager: systemct1 status ModemManager.service for details
Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack: see systemct1 status avahi-daemon.service for details
Failed to start Accounts Service: system ct1 status accounts-daemon.service for details
Failed to start Disk Manager: status udisks2.service for details
Failed to start Network Manager: see systemct1 status NetworkManager.service for details
DEPEND Dependency failed for Network Manager Wait Online.
Failed to start Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures; see systemct1 status kerneloops.service for details
Failed to start Login Service: see systemct1 status systemd-logind.service for details.
Failed to start System Logging Service: see systemct1 status.rsyslog.service for details
Failed to start Network Manager…
Failed to start Login Service: see systemct1 status systemd-logind.service for details.
Failed to start Gnome Display Manager: see systemct1 gdm.service for details
Failed to start System Logging Service…
Failed to start System Login Service…
```

Every time it says `Started D-Bus System Message Bus` it fails at something… This is a partial list. WPA supplicant and Accounts Service aren’t listed. Then it tries

```
snapd.servicessnapd.serice
Alsa-restore.servicelsa-restore.service
```

…then a dbus service.

I liked the environment I crafted for my girlfriend, and I don't want to admit to my brother I might need his used Windows laptop to play Civ 6. How do I retrieve this distro?

Comment: Explain in detail what you did to break your system. Do not reply in comments, edit your question.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've done my best to recall the steps leading to system malfunction in the question.  My previous question, "Challenges to Creating and Using Swap Files" contains the rest of that fruitless discussion.  Fact is, I don't know what happened - that's why I'm here asking for help.  My best guess would be that the swap file I made outstripped the memory resources needed to call bootable processes.  Either that, or the multiple improper shutdowns with the power button somehow messed up same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your commentary and advice.  It seems clear to me now that, while the file system seems healthy enough, the community indicates the boot service is FUBAR and I should reinstall.  I ask, would I rather repair a boot service for the first time, or reinstall 18.03 and modify to Yosemite MacUbuntu a second time?  I will go with the latter, creating an active swap partition to afford that memory as need be.